# あかさたなはまやらわ mnemonics

Tags: words, expressions, pronunciation

What mnemonic phrase / jingle, if any, is used by Japanese children to memorize the あかさたなはまやらわ sequence?

Or could you come up with some?

To help myself memorize this, I could possibly fashion an English jingle (where Satana is doomed to figure), but a straight Japanese sentence would be more suitable as a mnemonic device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Japanese children do not use special mnemonics. I mastered the sequences of あかさたなはまやらわ, いきしちにひみいりい, うくすつぬふむゆるう, えけせてねへめえれえ and おこそとのほもよろを using the latter half of [this children's song](https://youtu.be/SXvITpB4j0c?t=69) (written by a [famous poet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuntar%C5%8D_Tanikawa)), and this was probably when I was a kindergartner. I still clearly remember these five sequences almost like standard words, although I have forgotten the remaining parts of the song. Children can remember something like this fairly quickly, and it's much harder for them to remember a long sentence.

If you are interested in mnemonics for JSL learners, please see Ben's answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what phrase is used by Japanese children but the sequence あかさたなはまやらわ is called go-juu-on (五十音). Wikipedia has these ones:

> Ah, Kana Symbols: Take Note How Many You Read Well. and
>
> Ah, Kana. Surely Take Note How Many You Read Well. and
>
> Kana Signs, Think Now How Much You Really Want (to learn them). and
>   also
>
> A Kind Samurai Told Naomi How My Yak Ran Wild.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goj%C5%ABon#Mnemonics